# установка нвидиа драйверов на дебиан

Tags: linux, nvidia

как установить драйвера для нвидиа на дебиан 535 или 550 версии? обычный nvidia-driver не подходит

Comment: Почему не подходит?

Comment: @andreymal у нвидии список совместимых видеокарт под каждый драйвер.

Comment: Оно не подходит, потому что не очень работает с программами для записи, к примеру обс с кодировщиком NEVC, или тот же gpu screen recorder, раньше на убунту стоял драйвер 535

Comment: Что такое "не очень работает"? Если на этой версии "не очень", то почему вы решили, что на других версиях будет "очень"?

Comment: Вообще, я как пользователь нвидиа, обс и gpu screen recorder могу подтвердить, что всё очень даже работает как минимум с версии 450 до версии 550 включительно, и версия из nvidia-driver тоже попадает в этот диапазон, и что за «не очень» у вас случилось, непонятно

Comment: сам не знаю почему, на nvidia-driver не работает, а на убунте с nvidia-driver-535 работало, кто подскажет какие репозитории нужно подключить чтобы скачать 535 версию?

Comment: Что такое «не работает»?

Comment: Посмотрите, написал выше про кодировщик и тд

Comment: Выше вы написали «не очень работает», и это не говорит вообще ни о чём. В чём конкретная проблема у вас?

Comment: Не удалось открыть кодек NVENC: функция не реализована. обс студио